# How do I print a NSString showing its escape characters?

Tags: debugging, nsstring

I have an NSString that is causing a bug. I need to be able to copy the string exactly as it is and paste into some other code to see if I can reproduce the bug.

When I look at the string in the debugger it shows the escape characters and I tried to copy it by eye, but I'm off by a few characters some how. Is there some way to print a version of the string that I can copy and paste into xcode and get a perfect copy of the original NSString?

For example is there some function that will take a string @"test \n\n\n  String"

and output to the console "test \n\n\n String" as opposed to 
"test

String" which I can not copy and paste into xcode.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to help you, if you describe what the bug is, and which code produces the bug. You could e.g. set breakpoints in your code, or single step though it, to identify the instruction that is problematic. I believe it is very hard to understand your problem if you focus at printing a string.

Comment: If you want to do a manual c/c to try on a test code for example, you could transform it into `NSData` (that should keep all the "hidden" characters), use a method to create an "exact" NSData from a string representation (there are many codes here in SO), and the do the reverse coding.